# query sql-table and change entities

Tags: sql

i'm writing a plugin and want to change entities based on a sql query.

```
function showTest()
{
    var result= "<button onClick='query(\"wp_users\")'>users</button>" .
                "<button onClick='query(\"wp_posts\")'>posts</button>" .
                "<div class='results'/>" . 
                "<script>
                     function query(table) {
                          var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
                          // query sql and display results in div
                     };";
     return result;                 
}
add_shortcode("test", "showTest");
```

How do i perform the query and display the results?

Comment: You are mixing up JavaScript and PHP. You can't put PHP/MySQL in a script tag or trigger with onclick attributes.

Comment: well that is my problem, my query(table) is (and has to be) a js-function and i think i need to call php-functions to query sql

Comment: You need to perform an AJAX request in JS to the server, which can then perform a PHP/MySQL request to the database and return the result. Teaching all this though A. Has nothing to do with WordPress and B. Is _far_ too broad a topic for a Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

You should gotten return from SQL first. And then print results. Use `$wpdb` class for SQL queries. 
If you wanna use native SQL queries something like this might helps you

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

But it`s very bad idea. Use [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) with preparing.

Comment: but this is php. the query has to happen after the button is pressed, so i have to that in the js function. How do i do that?

Comment: You can`t create SQL query on native JS or jquery. Angular or node.js can doing sql queries. Also you can send jquery.ajax request on your server, build your query and send back sql response.

Comment: can u give me an example, how i do that?

Comment: i have tried so many examples i found googling and nothing worked

Comment: Read about jQuery.ajax(); it`s very simple.
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'your_php_script_url',
type: 'post' (or get),
data: {your data from front to backl-end},
success: function(response){
// Function calls when ajax request successfully returned
}
});

in php script do your sql script and by echo command send data back.

Comment: Wordpress have complex for ajax requests.  https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

add_action('wp_ajax_{YOUR_ACTION}', 'function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_{YOUR_ACTION}', 'function');